# bash - how to use if loop correctly

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement

I am fairly new to scripting and am currently trying to make a simple if else loop that goes through a file that has both ipaddress and hostname listed in there. It basically checks if they are online.

This is what I have:

```
for ip in `cat /tmp/blabla2 | awk '{print $1}'` ; do
if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
fqdn=`host $ip | awk '{print $5}'`
echo "$ip $fqdn is UP"
else
fqdn=`host $ip | awk '{print $5}'`
echo "$ip $fqdn is DOWN"
fi
done
```

Something I have a hard time understanding is how to include the hostname without using something like host $ip

It seems unnecessary to have to do another host lookup when the hostname is already on the same line in /tmp/blabla2

I've tried messing with variables in the if loop using awk print but no luck.

Any tips / tricks on this?
Thanks for your time

Comment: Why do you pipe blabla2 to awk to print only the first column?

Comment: the test file 'blabla2' contains this:
123.123.123.123      test.com

Comment: Would it not suffise to just print $2 instead of $1?

Comment: I guess that would work as well yes but how would I then list the IP address? That's basically what I am stuck on at the moment. Echoing both $ip and $fqdn ..

thanks man.

Comment: I guess you want to assign two variables at the same time.  Check this example `read a b < <(echo 1 2); echo $a $b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't read lines of a file in a `for` loop ([reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)). The `read` command can read more than one word from the lines of your file.

```
while read -r ip host; do
    if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "$ip $host is UP"
    else
        echo "$ip $host is DOWN"
    fi
done < /tmp/filename
```

Indentation is really important to be able to maintain your own code.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I do try to keep indentation correctly but find it hard to do on stackoverflow.

Thanks for your answer. That helped me a lot. :)

Comment: regarding indentation, I often write code in my editor and paste it into the answer box here. See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (`ctrl-k` is useful)